# Dynamically change the value of enum in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dynamic, enums

Have a look at the following code:

```
// typescript enum example
enum foo { ONE = 1, TWO = 2, THREE = 3 }
```

Is it possible to change the value of ONE to 0 in runtime? If yes, how?

Comment: It would be useful if you explained your use case. An `enum` is usually selected specifically because it is immutable - i.e. you would never want the values to change as it would make your application unpredictable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the typescript compiler will allow this. But why would you want to change an `enum`? The whole point is to have named constant values. If you want them to change, why not just use something like this:

```
const foo = {
  ONE: 1,
  TWO: 2,
  THREE: 3
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to change the value of ONE to 0 in runtime? If yes, how?

You can always use a *type assertion*:

```
// typescript enum example
enum foo { ONE = 1, TWO = 2, THREE = 3 }

(foo as any).ONE = 0;
```

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html But I don't recommend it.

Why not just write the following in the first place?:

```
enum foo { ONE = 0, TWO = 2, THREE = 3 }
```