# Is it possible to get the value of enums from a service in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, angular-services

I have an enum created which for the moment are keys and value dynamic but now the value it need to come from a service as display text and I am not finding anyway how to do that.
I need only the value to get from a service not to change dynamic that will be only one value with text 
This is the enum.

```
const enum Test {
Test1 = 'this is test 1',
Test2 = 'this is test 2',
Test3 = 'this is test 3',
Test4 = 'this is test 4',
}
```

From now the text comes from another platform with an URL which I need to show in Interpolation or Property Binding for example.

```
Test1 = this.textService.getText('here the id of the text'),
```

The getText method in Service

```
public getText(key: string, isGeneralKey = false): string {
  let searchKeys: string[];
  let result: string | DisplayTextMap;

  searchKeys = key.split('.');
  result = (isGeneralKey
    ? this.generalTexts[searchKeys[0]]
    : this.texts[searchKeys[0]]) as DisplayTextMap;

  if (result && searchKeys[1]) {
    result = result[searchKeys[1]];
  }
  if (result) {
    return this.decodeUnicodeTextService.getDecodedText(result as string);
  }
  return `${key} not found`;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't really understand what your problem is? Is there an error message? Also, why are you trying to use `enum` for a dynamic value? It seems to me intuitively not suitable to use `enum` for a dynamic value

Comment: @canbax I am trying to use `enum` for Dynamic Value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically change the value of enum in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366885/dynamically-change-the-value-of-enum-in-typescript)

Comment: @canbax Nope I declare the enum with `const` and that doesn't help me because I don't want to change in 1 2 or a text but I want to call a service there at value ?

Comment: You shouldn't use an `enum` for this... build your own enum-like object instead.

Comment: Like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#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)

Comment: @jcalz thats is what i wanted :) add as answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`const enum`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums)  cannot have computed members at all.  A numeric `enum` that isn't `const` can have computed members, but unfortunately an `enum` with string members cannot. I don't know if there's good documentation about this, but there's at least one [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25896) about how the error messages you get are misleading.  Anyway, the main point is: you can't do this with an `enum`.

Luckily you probably don't really need an `enum`.  Often you can replace an `enum` with a `const` object with `readonly` properties initialized to the values you care about, like this:

```
    const asReadonly = <T>(t: T): { readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] } => t
    const Test = asReadonly({
        Test1: this.textService.getText('here the id of the text'),
        Test2: this.textService.getText('here is a different id'),
        Test3: this.textService.getText('you get the idea'),
        Test4: this.textService.getText('etc')
    });
```

(Note that the above `asReadonly()` only makes the properties readonly at compile time.  If you want readonly at runtime also, you can have it return `Object.freeze(t)` instead of `t`.)

Then you can use the properties of `Test` the way you would with the `enum` value:

```
const someVal = Test.Test2; // string
```

There are some differences between a `const` object and an `enum`, but they might not matter for your use case.  And you can probably fix those if they do.

For example: an `enum` introduces named *types* as well as named values.  Since your values are computed, though, you can't do much better than using `string` as your type.  If you want to prevent someone copying random `string` values into somewhere you expect your enum you could maybe use a [branded primitive](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) type:

```
const asEnum = <T, N extends string>(t: T, n: N) =>
    Object.freeze(t) as { readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] & { __brand: N } };

const Test = asEnum({
    Test1: this.textService.getText('here the id of the text'),
    Test2: this.textService.getText('here is a different id'),
    Test3: this.textService.getText('you get the idea'),
    Test4: this.textService.getText('etc')
}, "Test");
type Test = typeof Test[keyof typeof Test];
```

And then you could use `Test` both as a value with properties and as a type:

```
function acceptTestEnumOnly(t: Test) { }
acceptTestEnumOnly(Test.Test3); // okay
acceptTestEnumOnly("oops"); // error!  "oops" is not assignable to Brand<"Test">
```

---

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFANiAlsJBvAUEkUvAPbBQAuSIUAShCACbloCeSAvEgDwAqAGiQA5JBAAelCMCZQkVAE7YA5gD4AFJQBcSQUmA7hASh24kCxi2DskAbQDSSbEgDWENqQBmugLo6+Dj5IAL5cqoTEkQDyAEYAVhDwlAB0nhYQAF4QmkYA3PgRRPAYUHIAwhgZGXiFkUgA9PXmEDAYiEiUABaYcgDumF3ypJBdKs0gaLWRUpIAyhAKAG6Y7dwEdRtIyhCUfBKU6uI6iipGeM2UAK4KOOJIANRIAEQAhC9PIVPEwV9EYCBuACiwEuYHUZ3Wm0iZAo1D2VC4NHollYbHUkKhG3hlAAjDpRlBkjNKPMlisIMltrt9uoAOSdBbILrITBMJBeDoMjr7WlGAS-THYgBM+O6hOJpOWiEpOz2kjpDIsTjkICQTEwnk8jOA1FZvP5mM22IAzKKekT9pLyTLqfLaR5LlsdpyWUxGPqBVDsQAWM3iy0LKUUqlyg60nbwXme75CJ7Yp55aNECxXG66aCUfJQn6RH61GEI7GI4AQXpICogKrg5L-IEgsGJ6HkBFQYYQABqE0R2OSwtyDSaJ2AygKedAkFgCGQACEFCAZBA2RinDqFp4p0hZ-OmDxRPtpLJ5JQlMPVDUoQB9C8xOcyQxZ7755vUWjA0GI-hCPeSA9yIdqTR-CEAwRDOThwihWIEiSVJ0iyHIkXOCxmFROxHGcNwPG8Pg-F0QIkAAMk3W8d2EM9gnyfMSnKSpqmXSJGmaVoNwJJB+kGVsRm6YdxkmKEJUDclEXozYQxpI4jxPZQIQua5bgeZ43g+HNNhUjZawgN8G3PQ0SGfdMEW4V963RJM6mxPFOXNASyWlMS7UVJkuVZdlvGZblJA9XTzIzEUrP9OZBLs2UaXpRllRoNUNS1CwdScJgvO84gTT9C1Ats4MQrtB0nWodzWXdPkzMiH1UpsoMbVDOkIyjbzgljeNG10lM5IMzMBTUz4n1hNri1LctaOrDStPBB8iEoNgYGQItuAmqaOWxWxMI5OaIAWjMfDGgcOkm6aM0Rf9COI7ceDjDMnnCbqWzbTs0G7DNe18-tGMOoitxkU740uyJPEuYAkkwcgaHgRAYGpKgtKiaw0W0NqZM6hBQfByhIeh9QexNPJttIFwQDYWpEZaZHUfYdQnlIUgYCgBNnqaBYFFIBQXiIcnKepiLgFIF9SkwZRQBiNAmVIY6PrOqgLvwYIgA)